# Using [FromBody] and able to handle an invalid input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

When using `[FromBody]` in a controller in ASP.NET Core (2.1 in this case), it handles all conversions to the specified model and makes sure the model is valid. This means that the controller method won't even get called if the supplied input is malformed.

1. How can I achieve that my controller method is being called even with invalid input so I can handle error cases by myself?
2. Is there a way to write my own middleware for it to log invalid inputs in the way my system needs it or is there even a default one which I could use?

Comment: Yes, it has. I use the default controller template being generated by dotnet cores mvc template.

Comment: There are multiple standalone dotnet core applications running. They all interact with each other. As we heavily rely on data but quality is insufficient, I want to be able to handle invalid requests for my own by either trying to fix them before turning them into a valid ModelState or spit out meaningful logging messages which can be reviewed by an engineer to fix it later. Because all of the services will do the same logging reporting, I thought maybe of a middleware which takes care for custom validation for everyone so that not every controller function needs to have a manual check.

Comment: Because first one is the most important thing. I would still be interested if there is a way to handle all of that automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asp.net core 2.1 the `ApiController` attribute has been [introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.1?view=aspnetcore-2.1#apicontroller-actionresultt) as the way to opt in to Web API-specific conventions and behaviors. Use the `CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1` flag in startup to set the level of [compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute).

The new behaviour is that validation errors will [automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses). As described in the documentation, it is quite easy to suppress this behaviour:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

In that case you can validate the models as usual:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

As for your second question, this is too broad:

> ... to log invalid inputs in the way my system needs it ...

There are [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1) (like `ExceptionFilterAttribute`) that you can use. Perhaps that is what you are looking for?